# cpanel xml-api php notice

Tags: php, cpanel

I'm getting the following notice,

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username'

........
```

and the code that generates it,

```
$acct = array(username => $username, password => $password, domain => $domain);
```

Ami doing something wrong here. the original code had something like this,

```
$acct = array( username => "someuser", password => "pass123", domain => "thisdomain.com");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try quoting the key, like so:

```
$acct = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'domain' => $domain);
```